# Object reference not set to an instance of an object-exception

Tags: asp.net

I have a panel with `ID:Panel2` in my web page and I'm adding adynamic table into it.

I'm getting an `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` exception.

My code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= val; i++)
            {
                Table Table4 = new Table();
                TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
                TableHeaderCell thc2 = new TableHeaderCell();
                thc2.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                thc2.BorderWidth = 2;
                TableHeaderCell thc3 = new TableHeaderCell();
                thc3.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                thc3.BorderWidth = 2;
                TableHeaderCell thc4 = new TableHeaderCell();
                thc4.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                thc4.BorderWidth = 2;
                TableHeaderCell thc5 = new TableHeaderCell();
                thc5.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                thc5.BorderWidth = 2;

                Label l2 = new Label();
                l2.Text = "Check Point";
                l2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                Label l3 = new Label();
                l3.Text = "Applicability";
                l3.ForeColor = Color.Black;

                Label l4 = new Label();
                l4.Text = "Effectiveness";
                l4.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                Label l5 = new Label();
                l5.Text = "Score";
                l5.ForeColor = Color.Black;

                thc2.Controls.Add(l2);
                thc3.Controls.Add(l3);
                thc4.Controls.Add(l4);
                thc5.Controls.Add(l5);
                thr.Cells.Add(thc2);
                thr.Cells.Add(thc3);
                thr.Cells.Add(thc4);
                thr.Cells.Add(thc5);
                Table4.Rows.Add(thr);
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                tr.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                tr.BorderWidth = 2;


                TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
                c2.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                c2.BorderWidth = 2;
                c2.Text = Convert.ToString(s[i]);
                TableCell c3 = new TableCell();
                c3.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                c3.BorderWidth = 2;
                TableCell c4 = new TableCell();
                c4.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                c4.BorderWidth = 2;

                TableCell c5 = new TableCell();
                c5.BorderColor = Color.Black;
                c5.BorderWidth = 2;

                DropDownList ddl1 = new DropDownList();
                ddl1.Items.AddRange(items2);
                ddl1.ID = "ddl1" + i;

                DropDownList ddl2 = new DropDownList();
                ddl2.Items.AddRange(items1);
                ddl2.ID = "ddl2" + i;
                TextBox t4=new TextBox();
                t4.ID = "textID4" + i;
                t4.EnableViewState = true;

                c2.ID = "newC2" + i;
                c3.ID = "newC3" + i;
                c4.ID = "newC4" + i;
                c5.ID = "newC5" + i;
                tr.ID = "newRow" + i;

                c3.Controls.Add(ddl1);
                c4.Controls.Add(ddl2);
                c5.Controls.Add(t4);

                tr.Cells.Add(c2);
                tr.Cells.Add(c3);
                tr.Cells.Add(c4);
                tr.Cells.Add(c5);
                Table4.Rows.Add(tr);

     ----->           this.Panel2.Controls.Add(Table4);

                Session["table"] = Table4;

            }
```

In line `(`this.Panel2.Controls.Add(Table4)`)`, I'm getting

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object-exception.

even though I have created a Panel in the design page I'm getting the error

Here any table is added dynamically not the Panel, Panel is created statically and I'm inserting dynamic table in it.

Comment: When is this code being executed?

Comment: the code is executed on a button click

Comment: So is this within the button click handler? Or somewhere else? Can you create a short but *complete* page which *just* shows the problem?

Comment: Can you ensure(with debugging) that `Panel2` is null at this line?

Comment: actually im writing the code in a method and calling the method in the button click event.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of reasons this can happen, but the most important is:

> Are you *absolutely sure* you have created a control with the **exact id**
>   with the **runat attribute set to "server"**?

This applies to both Panel2 and Table4.

Other than that you need to check these things:

- Your class (where the exception is occuring) is inheriting from System.UI.Page
- The @Page CodeBehind attribute is set to your class (spelling, capitalisation)
- You're referencing the object at the correct time during the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) (i.e. before it's being initialised)
- There's no where that the reference has been modified prior to use